# How do I sample only non-null values in R?

Tags: r, sampling

Is there was a way to sample only non-null values in R? Currently, I have this code.

```
s <- sample(200000, replace=TRUE);
m <- mydata$myvar[s]
```

However, some elements of `m` are null. Is there such a simple command as the following?

```
s <- sample(200000, replace=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE);
s <- sample(mydata$myvar, replace=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE);
```

The documentation does not state such option exists.

Comment: Are you sure you get NULL and not NA ? I get NA when I try to access indices out of bounds.

Comment: What is the output of `length(mydata$myvar)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the `NULL` elements afterwards:

```
m <- m[!is.null(m)]
```

Answer (score 2):

May be your data does not contains 200000 rows.

```
s <- sample(1:nrow(mydata),200000, replace=TRUE);

#replce =TRUE or FALSE as per your requirement

m <- mydata$myvar[s]
```

Try this hope it ll work

Comment: Better yet, `sample(nrow(mydata), ...` so that the object `1:nrow(mydata)` need not be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

`?na.omit`

or `?complete.cases` if you just need to index by it